Reading and visualizing memory using GDB in realtime
Hi I notice that SEGGER Sysview has the ability to disaply tracing data in realtime. It implements an internal binary data format which can encode the tracing data and store in the buffer on RAM of the target device. I'm wondering how can we use GDB and plus some script to implement that feature? For example, display a global variable which represents the CPU load in realtime and plotting into a diagram, etc.?
I'm not sure if watch command plus a while loop and continue command in GDB can achieve that?

This is often called live watch. You can't do that with gdb precisely; watch+breakpoint on some periodic function+continue does work but it is  very much not the same. Break/continue will mess with the execution of the target to an extent; it might be OK for your case, it might be very much not.
